# Cron expression difference between */5 and 0/5

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a cron properties file and some of the properties contain expression like:

```
"* 0/5 * * * ?"
```

and some of them contain:

```
"* */5 * * * ?"
```

What is the difference between the two?

If I want to run every 5 minutes then which one should be used?

Thanks

PS: My project is using spring scheduler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `"*/5 * * * * *"` for every 5 minutes and `0 0/5 8-10 * * *` for every 5 minutes between 8  o'clock and 10  o'clock

For more info [read this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

Comment: I also thought the same way - 0/5 runs on intervals like 00:05, 00:10, etc and */5 runs on every 5th minute after it starts so it could be like 00:03, 00:08, etc. Needed some clarification.

Comment: with 0/5 expression, let's say at 00:15 the process interrupted. Then 00:20 will execute? Or is it dependent on implementation?